# Does the lemma remain valid in b-metric space?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space.

$$CB(X)=\{A : A \text{ is a nonempty closed and bounded subset of }X \},$$
$$D(A,B)=\inf \{d(a,b) : a\in A , b\in B\},$$
$$\sigma (A,B)=\sup \{d(a,b) : a\in A , b\in B\},$$
$$H(A,B)=\max \{\sup_{x\in B} D(x,A) , \sup_{x\in A} D(x,B)\}.$$

**Lemma:**
Let $A,B\in CB(X)$, and let $x\in A$. Then, for each $\alpha>0$, there exists a $y\in B$ such that
\begin{equation}
d(x,y)\leq H(A,B)+\alpha.
\end{equation}

Question : How can we prove the lemma, and that this lemma remains valid in b-metric space?

A b-metric space means the same as metric space, with triangle inequality replaced with: $$\exists s\ge 1:\quad \forall x,y,z\in X:\quad d(x,z)\le s\big(d(x,y)+d(y,z)\big).$$

Comment: What's "b-metric space"?

Comment: The same definition of metric space just the difference in the triangular inequality.

Comment: Please give a complete definition

Comment: Let X be a nonempty set and s≥1 be a given real number. A function d:X×X→R+ is a b-metric on X if for all x,y,z∈X the following conditions hold:\
d ( x , y ) = 0 if and only if x = y .
d ( x , y ) = d ( y , x ).
d ( x , z ) \leq s [ d ( x , y ) + d ( y , z ) ].
In this case, the pair (X,d) is called a b-metric space.